# Can I show the content of a file in a browser somehow before downloading that file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I wondering whether you can view a file in the browser or something before downloading that file so that the user can decide whether he wants to download a file or not (for example choosing the wrong file) in NodeJS?

I have the following code to download a file:

```
app.get("/download/file", (req, res) => {
  let dir = basicPath + req.query.path + '/' + req.query.fileName;
  const file = path.resolve(dir);
  res.download(file)
});
```

Is it even possible for some file extension to be shown before downloading? I know for example that you can view PDF's in the browser and decide whether you can download it but if you had a text file with the extension .txt could you view such files without downloading it first?

Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: The main difference is `res.download()` and `res.sendFile()` but from the point of view of HTTP they're the same except for one header: "Content-disposition"

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I will take a look at the function ```sendFile()``` and I hope that is the function I need to solve my problem!

Comment: @slebetman It does download the file again but I want to view that file before downloading somehow, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the browser to **display some content**, the browser actually **needs to download it**. As @slebetman says, `Content-Disposition` header may help for your purpose, but the file needs to be downleader either way. That header will say to the browser to use the file inline within the requested webpage or to request store it in the device.

**That's how Internet works**: You connect to a remote server to download for the browser some content to display. Some content that both you do not have and you do not know anything about it.

**Browser's POV**: If the file is not downloaded, such file does not exist (not even I'm aware of it).

You said:

> Is it even possible for some file extension to be shown before downloading? I know for example that **you can view PDF's in the browser** and ***decide*** whether you can **download it** but if you had a text file with the extension .txt could you view such files without downloading it first?

I encourage you to use browsers' network tools (right click + inspect), so you will see that those files are actually downloaded on your side. There, the *decission* you have (if you want to call it that way) is to locally store it or not (in other words, move from a tmp folder to a folder of your choice).

**Approach to your question**: If you do not want to send full file, you could create **previews** (for example, trim a PDF file and store also the first pages). That way, the *original* file is not downloaded until user request so. But some content is downloaded to the browser, anyway.